# Проблема 10k соединений

Tags: c, веб-программирование, nginx

Я написал программу на Си. Что будет, если ее одновременно вызовут два раза?

Пример: есть приложение - веб-сервер, nginx или самописный.
Чтобы приложение не завершилось, а процесс висел, в нем прописан бесконечный цикл `while(true)`, а внутри цикла проверяется подключение к сокету. Предположим, поступило одновременно два запроса. Очередная итерация `while(true)` примет первый запрос, а второй отклонится?
Или эти запросы будут висеть в какой-то очереди, и после двух последовательных итераций цикла они по очереди выполнятся?

Я задаю этот вопрос потому, что меня интересует проблема 10k соединений. Каким параметром ограничивается максимальное количество соединений на веб-сервер?

Comment: Так вы написали или nginx уже написанный и очень грамотно с использованием целого набора технологий позволяющих обрабатывать множество запросов одновременно ? Есть разные виды ограничений, например количество открытых файлов одним процессом и оно не велико, но легко решается размножением процесса. плюс грамотное мультипрексикрование поступающих запросов внутри одного процесса, возможно с применением многопоточности, если асинхронности не хватает

Comment: nginx привел для примера. На самом деле интересует как процесс который живет вечно - nginx например - будет обрабатывать множество запросов? Теоретически после чтения внутри while(true) выполняется обработка запроса, и в этот момент остальные запросы не обрабатываются

Comment: разумеется одно ядро процессора не может одновременно обрабатывать более одного запроса. Поэтому приложение должно использовать многопоточность с количеством конкурирующих потоков немногим более количества ядер. Или не потоков, а отдельных процессов. Или несколько многопоточных процессов

Comment: Что означает «одновременно вызовут два раза»? Если имеется в виду запуск исполняемого файла два раза, то просто запустится два процесса, и ничего особенного не произойдёт. Если только сама программа не делает что-нибудь особенное

Comment: Про nginx — почитайте про асинхронное программирование и поймёте суть

Comment: @andreymal читал асинхронное программирование на примере node js. Но например nginx - он создает новый поток для каждого соединения? Потом идет на python, вызывает его код - тем самым создав новый процесс, который завершится по окончании скрипта, и полученный результат отдастся клиенту в браузер? А поток закроется?

Comment: Когда мы запускаем node js, то это один процесс в ОС. Он не убивается сразу потому, что в нем есть бесконечный цикл, который при каждой итерации проверяет сокет. Вопрос - что будет, если одновременно поступят два запроса? Два человека с разных браузеров обратятся на мой веб-сервер?

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов nginx тоже может работать в одном процессе/потоке, как и node js, и потоков он не создаёт. Пока nginx ждёт ответа от «python», он вместо того, чтобы ждать и ничего не делать, вполне может заняться обработкой какого-нибудь другого запроса — таким образом можно обрабатывать хоть тысячи запросов в одном потоке условно одновременно (более правильное слово — конкурентно, если правильно помню). В node js всё по сути то же самое, но ожидается не «python», а данные от какой-нибудь базы данных например; пока ожидается ответ от базы данных — можно начать обрабатывать второй запрос

Comment: понятно, спасибо. Но есть вопрос. Как все же поступит node js или nginx, если на него одновременно поступят два запроса? Они складываются в очередь?

Comment: и вопрос 2. Если так, то каким параметром ограничивается количество максимальных одновременных соединений?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89171/discussion-between---and-andreymal).

Comment: А что вы понимаете под очередью ? Очередь где ? Ядро ОС после приема запроса на коннект поставит его в свою очередь на отдачу процессу, которой может его принять. Так же оно после открытия соединиения буферизирует поступающие данные, опять же пока процесс не заберет. Поэтому асинхронному процессу нет особого смысла делать у себя дополнительные очереди. Потому как сам механизм сокетов ОС уже это обеспечивает.

Comment: И напоминаю свой свой первый коммент: nginx плюс ко всему запускает несколько процессов и ядро новые соединения отдает по очереди им (опять же это основа механизма сокетов ОС), следовательно более одного запроса могут быть обработаны физически одновременно.

Comment: И еще раз напомню свой первый коммент, основное ограничение на количество соединений - это количество открытых файлов на один процесс. И его редко удается поднять выше 4096 (при желании и это можно). Но это проблемой не является, опять же из за того что програма использует несколько процессов, а у каждого процесса своя таблица дескрипторов. А при большом желании можно даже делать не полноценный процесс, а что то среднее между процессом и потоком с использованием clone()

Comment: @Mike спасибо. ОС собирает соединения в своей очереди. Затем создается новый сокет, на каждый сокет - свой процесс. И на один процесс одно соединение. andreymal сказал что там так же может применяться асинхронность. Но тогда откуда берется проблема 10 тысяч соединений? Если

Comment: Нет, на каждый сокет свой процесс слишком расточительно. Вы какую то не ту литературу читали про асинхронность. Потому что понятие асинхронности - это когда один процесс обрабатывает сразу множество соединений, т.е. сокетов. И в принципе один процесс вполне может держать 1000 соединений. Никакой проблемы 10к соединений не существует, при должным образом написанном коде. Такая проблема возникает только из за неправильного кода (например из за попытки обрабатывать каждое соединение в отдельном потоке, как вы предполагаете. Переключение потоков слишком дорогая операция, что бы делать 10к потоков)

Comment: Возможно вы еще не понимаете какие задачи выполняет тот же nginx. Что бы "обработать" web-соединение не нужно много процессорного времени. Основная задача таких серверов, принять запрос, понять о чем он, отправить запрос на соответсвующую обработку другому процессу (в случае cgi) или запросить у ядра ОС отдачу файла в сокет (статический контент). Подождать результата, вернуть результат клиенту, подождать подтверждения клиента. 99% всей "обработки" - это ожидание чего либо. И пока идет ожидание процесс выполняет работу для других соединений

Comment: Возьми libuv и не изобретайте велосипед. Она простая как пробка. Есть тики от таймера, есть сокеты ожидающие. Каждый тик опрашивается сокет на на поступившие данные с таймаутом таким чтоб всех успеть опросить. Если данные есть, то стартуем калбак в фоновом потоке. А луп крутится дальше

Answer (score 0):

Вы поднимаете очень большую и сложную тему. Краткого ответа дать невозможно.

На сайте разработчиков IBM есть великолепная статья (точнее - русский перевод) на эту тему, под названием:

> Пример разработки сервера с поддержкой пользовательских сессий на
>   языке C в ОС GNU/Linux

Почитайте ёё!

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-server1/index.html

Comment: А нет ли ссылки на оригинал? Это серия статей, на русский перевели только первую часть из пяти

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов  *А нет ли ссылки на оригинал?*. Не знаю. Вообще-то, автором статьи является  Александр Андреев. И не говорится. что это - перевод. Так что, не факт, что этот "оригинал" на самом деле существует. Во всяком случае, на сайте IBM я такого не нашёл.